# Ursina's "FirstPersonController" player movement is blocked by update method

Tags: ursina

I'm working on a game in Ursina where player receives damage and is able to regenerate health when there is no danger nearby. I planned to do this by using the default "update" function for the Player class, which inherits from the standard `FirstPersonController` class.

The idea is that with update function, the game checks how much health the player has and if its below 100, it slowly regenerates it.

However, when I put this regeneration function inside update, the player control freezes completely. I cant walk nor look around with mouse. All the other methods I made for player, work for some reason and I know it's not the game that is frozen but the player.

To check that I even made an empty function that just returns when called in the update update and the exact same thing happens.

I then tried making simple movement for the player, such as:

```
def move(self):
        if held_keys["w"]:
            self.x += 3 * time.dt
```

and when I launch the game, and press "w", the player actually moves. This leads me to conclusion that if you create the update function for the `FirstPersonController` class, it blocks all the controls for some reason.

So, my question is, can this problem be fixed somehow ?